# Crypto in Angular and BCrypt in Java did not match

Tags: java, angular, bcrypt

I have the code in java block below

```
public static String hashPassword(String password_plaintext) {
        return BCrypt.hashpw(password_plaintext, BCrypt.gensalt());
    }

    public static boolean checkPassword(String password_plaintext, String stored_hash) {
        return BCrypt.checkpw(password_plaintext, stored_hash);
    }

    public static String generateMD5(String text) {
        MessageDigest md;
        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            byte[] messageDigest = md.digest(text.getBytes());
            BigInteger number = new BigInteger(1, messageDigest);
            String hashtext = number.toString(16);
            return hashtext;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return text;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "0c35eedfd013e5efa72d8c756b3f22a0";
        String b = generateMD5("491866");
        String c = hashPassword(b);
        System.out.println(checkPassword(a,c));
    }
```

and in angular, I use

```
Crypto.MD5('491866').toString()
```

for generating the password, but the output is false

and then I try to test with the password 123456 ==> the output is true
.Could you advise me what's wrong here? 90% of the checkPassword worked well, but sometimes no.

Comment: Using `new BigInteger(1,bytes).toString(16)` to convert to hex **removes any leading zeros**. Your test value has a leading zero, and removing it makes a different _string_ (and password) even though it represents the same integer in hex. 1/16 of possible inputs (just over 6%) will have a hex hash with a leading zero.

Comment: Hi @dave_thompson_085,
Do we have the solution for this?

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085,
I use the new way for this and it's working now
DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(messageDigest).toLowerCase();